# Unable to connect Android device using adb

Tags: android, adb

I am connecting my Samsung Galaxy Tab to my macbook via USB.

I used to be able to pulling file from my Galaxy Tab using adb but all of a sudden I can't do so.

I can see my device using `adb devices`
but when using `adb -e shell`, it prompt **error: device not found**

Device already turned on the USB debug mode.

What's going wrong? Anyone can help?

P.S. My galaxy Tab was running out of battery before, if it has anything to do with it (?)

Answer (score 3):

Few things you could try:

1. On your device go to Settings > Storage > USB Computer Connection > Select Camera(PTP) mode.
2. If you are using eclipse change the Base local debugger port to something like 8601. Increase the ADB connection time. Also put a check in box that says, Use ABDHOST.

Comment: for 1, No such setting in galaxy tab. Mine is P1000 with firmware version 2.2

for 2, I am not using eclipse but simply use the command prompt on mac os

Comment: On my tablet(Runnning 4.1) once in storage i have to click the button in upper right, looks like three blocks on top of each other? And that's where i found the PTP preference. 

The three things in number 2, i would think should be doable on commandprompt, since eclipse preferences is just GUI for changing ADB settings, what those commands are idk, but these steps got my tablet working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fixed it: in Manifest.xml had

```
  android:minSdkVersion="11"
  android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

and changed it to

```
 android:minSdkVersion="10"
  android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Now I can debug on my Samsung Ace and other devices

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get those messages only when there are no instances of emulator or device running and talking with adb. Even with the device/emulator connected, chances are that adb is losing connection with them. Usually, I do one of `adb reset/Kill-server/start-server` to restore normalcy

Comment: The commands themselves work, i.e. i can restart the server, but still unable to fix my problem.

Comment: same problem i am facing. I also can not able to connect my samsung GALAXY ACE DUOS to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to more than one device/emulator connected.

check `adb devices` if it shows more than one device then it might not be able to connect to emulators; run `adb usb` it will restart other devices, then disconnect/reconncet usb cable, now run `adb devices` it should show only one device, now do:

`adb backup -apk -noshared -all -f Backup_11_30_2014.ab <------(WORKED FOR ME)`

OR

`adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\NAME\backup.ab <---(THIS ONE HANGS)`

[Tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/125375/how-to-create-a-full-android-phone-or-tablet-backup-without-rooting-or-unlocking-your-device/) that I found.

Answer (score -4):

To solve

error: device not found!:   OR adb: unable to connect for backup

1) enable "DEVELOPER OPTIONS" in device settings by 7x tapping Build No field under "About phone"

2) in the now available "DEVELOPER OPTIONS" - enable "USB debugging"

3) go to http://clockworkmod.com/carbon/drivers and download drivers for your device, unpack archive and go to "device manager on your operating sustem, where you'll find the (unrecognized or recognized) device name (Nexus 5 in my case)

Right click and update drivers.

4) Run the ADB tool or the HOLO BACKUP mod of that to backup your device.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!